# Factory_bot_rails create hash with trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I want to create hash like below using `factory_bot_rails`

```
let(:expected_hash) do
  {
    'fields' => {
      'summary' => 'member added as a collaborator to repository',
      'description' => "[OutsideCollaboratorAdded]\n-----------------\nMember: member,\n Added to project: repository,\n by: sender",
      'project' => { 'id' => '22501' },
      'issuetype' => { 'id' => '11800' },
      'customfield_14400' => '2020-04-23'
    }
  }
end
```

The idea is to have these fields: `summary`, `description`, `project` and `issue_type` to be editable by using `trait`. So I was trying to something like:

```
  factory :expected_ticket_fields do
    fields {{
      summary => 'test',
      description => 'test desc',
      customfield_14400 => '2020-04-23'
      }}

    trait :member_added do
      summary { 'member added as a collaborator to repository' }
      description { '[OutsideCollaboratorAdded]\n-----------------\nMember: member,\n Added to project: repository,\n by: sender' }
      project {{ 'id' => '22501' }}
    end
  end
```

And in specs:

```
  before do
    hash = create(:expected_ticket_fields)
    hash.member_added
  end
```

But I'm getting an error: `uninitialized constant ExpectedTicketFields`

Comment: You would have to use OpenStuct as the class for the factory. `factory :expected_ticket_fields, class: 'OpenStruct' do ...`. But IMHO this looks like something that should be handled by a model.

Comment: What is the purpose of the hash? As max said, that looks like it should be a model and not a hash.

Comment: Guys, I want to create a hash by factory_bot so the rest is irrelevant I guess. If you really want to know it creates a Jira ticket and it's a part of bigger class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :apple_store_webhook, class: Hash do
    product_id { "test_recurring_2" }
    notification_type { "DID_RENEW" }
    subtype { "VOLUNTARY" }
    expires_date { 1.month.from_now.in_time_zone.to_i * 1000 }
    purchase_date { Time.zone.now.to_i * 1000 }
    original_purchase_date { Time.zone.now.to_i * 1000 }
    signed_date { Time.zone.now.to_i * 1000 }

    initialize_with do
      {
        "transactionId" => "1000000899870910",
        "originalTransactionId" => "1000000883101707",
        "webOrderLineItemId" => "1000000067144880",
        "bundleId" => "com.some.bundleId",
        "productId" => product_id,
        "subscriptionGroupIdentifier" => "20518733",
        "purchaseDate" => purchase_date,
        "originalPurchaseDate" => original_purchase_date,
        "expiresDate" => expires_date,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "type" => "Auto-Renewable Subscription",
        "inAppOwnershipType" => "PURCHASED",
        "signedDate" => signed_date,
        "notificationType" => notification_type,
        "subtype" => subtype,
        "notificationUUID" => "65d80713-d686-41ba-b587-61e0f39d28d9"
      }
    end

    trait :refund_webhook do
      after(:build) do |hsh|
        hsh["revocationDate"] = Time.zone.now.to_i * 1000
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

Should work like this:

```
[13] pry(main)> FactoryBot.build :apple_store_webhook, :refund_webhook, notification_type: "FOO"
=> {
                  "transactionId" => "1000000899870910",
          "originalTransactionId" => "1000000883101707",
             "webOrderLineItemId" => "1000000067144880",
                       "bundleId" => "com.some.bundleId",
                      "productId" => "test_recurring_2",
    "subscriptionGroupIdentifier" => "20518733",
                   "purchaseDate" => 1637651271000,
           "originalPurchaseDate" => 1637651271000,
                    "expiresDate" => 1640243271000,
                       "quantity" => 1,
                           "type" => "Auto-Renewable Subscription",
             "inAppOwnershipType" => "PURCHASED",
                     "signedDate" => 1637651271000,
               "notificationType" => "FOO",
                        "subtype" => "VOLUNTARY",
               "notificationUUID" => "65d80713-d686-41ba-b587-61e0f39d28d9",
                 "revocationDate" => 1637651271000
}
```

Comment: Super helpful to example. I was struggling for a few hours to understand how to have nested hash attributes overwritable in FactoryBot style. Thank you @retgoat!

Answer (score 0):

FactoryBot works differently than you are using it.

1) FactoryBot is *not* a Hash, it's a type of FactoryBot object.
2) An ActiveRecord of the same name needs to exist (like "Ticket" or "Project") for FactoryBot to work.

You'd want to create a trait, then if you want that kind of Ticket, you'd write it this way:

```rb
factory :ticket do
  # you can specify the default `summary`
  summary { 'This is a ticket' }
  trait :ticket_with_member_added do
    summary { 'This is a ticket with a member added' }
    description { '[OutsideCollaboratorAdded]\n-----------------\nMember: member,\n Added to project: repository,\n by: sender' }
    # If you are planning on using a Project ActiveRecord, then you must ALSO create a factory for project, then this will trigger a Project to be created.
    project
  end
end

# In your tests
ticket = create(:ticket_with_member_added)
```